Cryptanalysis of xorshift + multiplication mixer
Suppose we have a $2w$-bit integer $s$, a $2w$-bit odd round key $k$, and some constant $c$ then we can define the following permutation:
s ^= s >> w;
s *= k;
s += c;

The idea behind this permutation is that the xorshift causes the lower bits to depend on the upper bits, whereas the multiplication causes the upper bits to depend on the lower bits (and the key). The addition of the constant prevents the zero fixed-point. This pattern is commonly seen in non-cryptographic hashes to finalize a hash, as it provides excellent avalanche properties with few rounds.
Has there been any proper cryptanalysis on this construct, or something similar? How many rounds would one need to reach a certain security level, if any is achieved ever?
